# How can I get the whitespace at the beginning of a line and use it in a search and replace?

Tags: vim

### Background

I want to convert an if statement from Fortran to C++. I like to have braces on a new line.

So I want to make

```
    ! this may be nested so indentation is unknown
    if ( condition ) then
        block
    end if
```

to

```cpp
    if ( condition )
    {
        block
    }
```

Changing `end if` to `}` is easy since the indentation is already how I want it. I just used `:%s/end if/}/gc`.

However, changing `then` is more challenging. I need to create a new line and set its the leading whitespace to the same as the previous line.
The closest I have to a solution is `:%s/then/\=printf("\n%s{",indent(line('.')))/gc`
However I want to use the value returned from `indent(line('.')` to set the number of indents.

### Problem

Can I use a number I receive from a function to set the number of tabs at the beginning of line in a search and replace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to substitute `then` with:

- a newline,
- followed by *n* spaces, as many as used for indenting the current line,
- followed by an opening brace.

As is, your command does the following:

- a newline,
- followed by the number of spaces used for the indentation of the current line,
- followed by an opening brace.

`:help repeat()` to the rescue:

```
:%s/then/\=printf("\n%s{",repeat(' ',indent(line('.'))))/gc
```

But there is still room for improvement…

- you only want to substitute trailing `then`s so the `g` flag is useless:

  ```
  :%s/then/\=printf("\n%s{",repeat(' ',indent(line('.'))))/c
  ```
- the search pattern may match other `then`s so it should be restricted a little:

  ```
  :%s/then\s*$/\=printf("\n%s{",repeat(' ',indent(line('.'))))/c
  ```
- also, the pattern should include any whitespace before the `then` to avoid leaving annoying trailing whitespace behind:

  ```
  :%s/\s*then\s*$/\=printf("\n%s{",repeat(' ',indent(line('.'))))/c
  ```
- `line('.')` is unnecessary:

  ```
  :%s/\s*then\s*$/\=printf("\n%s{",repeat(' ',indent('.')))/c
  ```
- and we could use the new-ish "method" syntax to limit parenthesis nesting:

  ```
  :%s/\s*then\s*$/\=repeat(' ',indent('.'))->printf("\n%s{")/c
  ```

Comment: Great. I did not know about `repeat` and thanks for the other suggestions that improve the command.